# How to extract all words before a match?

Tags: javascript, regex

is there any regex that would separate the `title` and the `address` to from the text to the output below?

**This is what i have so far:**

```
.+?(?=\d+.*Singapore \d{6}\b)
```

**Text:**

```
Marina Bay Sands Relocated! 2 Bayfront Avenue Galleria Level #B1-01 Singapore 018972
+65 6634 9969
nex 23 Serangoon Central #B1-10 Singapore 556083
+65 6634 7787
Northpoint City 1 Northpoint Drive South Wing #B1-107 Singapore 768019
+65 6481 3433
```

**Output:**

```
Marina Bay Sands Relocated! 
2 Bayfront Avenue Galleria Level #B1-01 Singapore 018972

nex 
23 Serangoon Central #B1-10 Singapore 556083

Northpoint City 1 Northpoint Drive South Wing #B1-107 Singapore 768019
+65 6481 3433
```

Comment: Maybe `/(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore \d{6})\b/`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0G0wH/1). The phone numbers should not land in the match, right?

Comment: i want to match too if possible thanks (:

Comment: Like https://regex101.com/r/i0G0wH/2? or https://regex101.com/r/i0G0wH/3?

Comment: regex101.com/r/i0G0wH/2 i believe this should suits my needs. However, the regex seems to match the full address and phone as well? I want it to be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore \d{6})\b(?:\r?\n(\+65\s*\d{4}\s*\d{4}))?
```

Or just

```
(.+?)\s*(\d+.*Singapore \d{6})\b(?:\r?\n(\+65[\d ]*))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0G0wH/6).

**Details**

- `(.+?)` - Group 1: any 1 or more chars other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+.*Singapore \d{6})` - Group 2: 1+ digits, any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, `Singapore`  and then six digits
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:\r?\n(\+65\s*\d{4}\s*\d{4}))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\r?\n` - CRLF or LF line ending
  - `(\+65\s*\d{4}\s*\d{4})` - Group 3: `+65`, 0+ whitespaces, 4 digits,  0+ whitespaces, 4 digits. The `[\d ]*` will match 0 or more digits or spaces.

Three group contents per match:

```
Marina Bay Sands Relocated!
2 Bayfront Avenue Galleria Level #B1-01 Singapore 018972
+65 6634 9969

nex
23 Serangoon Central #B1-10 Singapore 556083
+65 6634 7787

Northpoint City
1 Northpoint Drive South Wing #B1-107 Singapore 768019
+65 6481 3433
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Great explanation. Im going to give this a thumbs up!! @Wiktor Stribizew

Comment: Stribizew I already gave you an upvote. Thanks for you help once again. Cheers!